# Array elements not preserved when assigned as object's attribute

Tags: java, arrays, oop, hashmap

I have created an instance of an array, shortFacilitiesArray, to modify a set of existing values in the array by adding additional ones. However, when I set the instance array as the attribute of my object all data is lost. My code is mostly as follows:

```
if(hotelMap.containsKey(hotelID)) {

    JSONArray shortFacilitiesJSON = jsonObj.getJSONArray("shortFacilities"); 
    String[] shortFacilitiesArray = (hotelMap.get(hotelID)).getFacilitiesShort();
    shortFacilitiesArray = new String[shortFacilitiesJSON.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<shortFacilitiesJSON.length();i++) {
            shortFacilitiesArray[i] = shortFacilitiesJSON.getString(i);             
    }

    hotelMap.get(hotelID).setFacilitiesShort(shortFacilitiesArray);
}
```

For example: 
if my shortFacilitiesArray is {"parking", "hairdryer"}
, after setting it as the array of the object in the map it will output null, null.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thank you for your comment. I cleaned the code in my question. An example of the problem is demonstrated below my code, last sentence of question.

Comment: `String[] shortFacilitiesArray = (hotelMap.get(hotelID)).getFacilitiesShort();`
    `shortFacilitiesArray = new String[shortFacilitiesJSON.length()];` why do you read the data and then reassing the array?

Comment: @dehasi I have a case that copies some info from the additional variables into variables but it is not relevant to the question. I simply want to access the array, modify it, and then assigned the modified version.

Comment: Thank you for reducing the amount of code. It's still not **complete** though: I can't copy it to a text editor and run it as there's so much context missing. An [MCVE](/help/mcve) should be both minimal *and* complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional context, my bet would be shortFacilitiesJson.GetString() is probably returning null and hence setting your initially populated array to an array of nulls. You can validate this by testing a scenario where the shortFacilitiesArray begins with a string. In this case, after running the program the   shortFacilitiesArray should contain all nulls except for the first element, which should be the same string as before.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. I tested such a scenario and despite  shortFacilitiesJson.GetString() returning a string, (not null). A case as the second one you mentioned exists in another part of my code and the result 
is indeed String, null, null, null... However it is not because of  shortFacilitiesJson.GetString() .

Comment: Can you use share the code for the setFacilitiesShort method?

Comment: public void setFacilitiesShort(String[] facilities) { this.facilitiesShort = facilitiesShort; }

Comment: In that case, the setFacilitiesShort method seems redundant. String arrays are a reference type, so when you change the content of the string array it should automatically update the object member as well.

Comment: True. However, should my code work despite the redundancy?